# Bootstrap Button With Twitter Typeahead Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form. Built with Bootstrap3. On this form I have twitter typeahead fields.

I need to be able to nest a button in the typeahead field as is standard with bootstrap.

When the form loads the button is part of the field. When the field is typed in the button shifts downwards approximately 4 pixels.

The HTML for that section of the form is:

```
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div  class="input-group" id="partTypeahead">  
                    <label for="Part Number">Part Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm typeahead" id="partNumber" placeholder="4+  Characters then Press Search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter At Least 4 Characters And Then Press Search Button">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs moveDown" type="button" id="showPart" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Go to Part"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

I have even tried adding a method to modify the button's css when the field is typed in and it simply ignores anything like that.

Comment: The label doesn't belong in the input-group; also, your input class is `sm` and your button class is `xs`. These different sizes may throw you off.

Comment: @Kramb good catch on those, unfortunately it did not fix the issue. But I do appreciate the tip on proper structure and the button size catch.

Comment: can you put the relevant code in a code-snippet (or fiddle)? a [mcve] always makes troubleshooting faster.  thx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the exact solution you are looking for, check out this:

The HTML:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
                <label for="Part Number">Part Number</label>
                <div class="input-group" id="partTypeahead">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm typeahead" id="partNumber" placeholder="4+  Characters then Press Search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter At Least 4 Characters And Then Press Search Button">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs moveDown" type="button" id="showPart" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Go to Part"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span></button>
                </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label{
  display:block;
}

input,button{
  min-height:30px;
}
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mndsilva/fpmabkhs/2/).

Comment: It seemed like that might have done it, made me hopeful because min-height for both is something I had not tried yet. But no dice. The button still shifts. Interestingly enough, the drop down menu for the typeahead has a small gap between the top of the menu and the field itself. The button shifts down so that the button's bottom is aligned with the top of the menu.